# Windows defender quarantined files, Win32/Uwamson.A!ml and now I have issues. Can I restore my GUI wallet without downloading entire blockchain?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, security, mnemonic-seed

I am trying and failing to restore my GUI wallet from mnemonic seed...
I have not accessed my wallet for over a year, I recently sent some funds to it. When I tried to view the current balance the daemon would not sync or connect.

I traced the issue, I think, to allowing Windows Defender anti-virus to quarantine files. It mentioned something about trojans being located in the monero directory, and being not very computer savvy, I panicked and deleted them! The file had the name of Win32/Uwamson.A!ml and I don't believe the file ever ran. After a lot of reading and research I came to the conclusion it may have been a geniune part of the Monero GUI wallet, which I verified correctly before downloading and installing.

I have tried to completely remove the wallet and all hidden files etc from my computer, then download, verify and install the wallet again.

Using my seed phrase and accurate restore height of 2276000, even with 62GB free on my hard drive it tries to sync the blockchain for hours, then I run out of disk space, and everything grinds to a halt.
Is it safe/possible to use an open remote node to restore and then use a wallet? I have never tried this way before.
Or, is it possible to download a pruned blockchain when restoring a wallet? If so, how?

It seems mad that I'd need to buy a seperate hdd just to download the now massive entire blockchain to access a relatively small amount of funds in my wallet.

I do also have a note of my secret and private view, secret and public spend keys, if that's of any use in restoring things.

Many thanks for any help here. I'm really not a technical minded person and this has been a very steep learning curve so far! It'd be lovely if Monero was more accessible to folks like me who don't want to spend days learning how it works!